# Function call in Javascript loop fails to work

Tags: javascript, html

The problem I am having is whenever I try to loop the `newRow()` function my web page does not do anything. I tried onload and it still doesn't work. I also used for loop; didn't work either. The table is still empty and the only way I can add another row is by clicking the "New Row" button.

Here is `my-webpage.html`:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            My First Webpage
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tables.js">
    </script>
    <h2>Game Development Research</h2>
    <h6>Compiled by Reuben Unicruz</h6>
        <hr>
    <h3><u><em>Games Analysis</em></u></h3>
    <h4>Halo 4</h4>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HMOWXHlxUM0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <br/>
        <hr>
    <h3><u><em>Game Mechanics</em></u></h3>
    <h4>First Person Shooters</h4>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/13iMO9s-q0c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <br/>
    <h4>Jumping in 2D</h4>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yuRRPT-Isp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <hr>
    <h3>Game Ratings</h3>
    <form>
        <table id="GameRating">
            <thead>
                <th>Title</th><th>Genre</th><th>Score</th>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="New Row" onClick="newRow()"></input>
        <input type="button" value="Delete Last Row" onClick="deleteLastRow()"></input>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the `tables.js` file:

```
function newRow()
{

    var table = document.getElementById("GameRating");

    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

    var title = row.insertCell(0);
    var genre = row.insertCell(1);
    var score = row.insertCell(2);

    title.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\"></input>";
    genre.innerHTML = "<select><option>Platformer</option><option>FPS</option><option>TPS</option></select>";
    score.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\"></input>";
}

function deleteLastRow()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("GameRating");

    table.deleteRow(table.rows.length - 1);
}

function printHello()
{
    document.write("HELLO!!!<br/>")
}

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    newRow();
}
```

Why does it not work?
By the way trincot, the answer you linked to was different from my situation since if I didn't call the `newRow()` function and used `document.write` instead, the for loop will work and the `document.write` function works. Also, the script is already arranged properly.

Comment: please add the rest of html part as well, and have a look here: [mcve].

Comment: But where is the loop?

Comment: where is your element with `GameRating` id?

Comment: Make sure your code is in a script you put after the content, just before the closing `</body>` tag. Otherwise it will try to access a table that is not yet available.

Comment: Just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet. Is this what you were trying to implement?

```js
function newRow()
{

    var table = document.getElementById("GameRating");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);

    var title = row.insertCell(0);
    var genre = row.insertCell(1);
    var score = row.insertCell(2);

    title.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\"></input>";
    genre.innerHTML = "<select><option>Platformer</option><option>FPS</option><option>TPS</option></select>";
    score.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\"></input>";
}
```

```html
<head>
        <title>
            My First Webpage
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tables.js">
    </script>
    <h2>Game Development Research</h2>
    <h6>Compiled by Reuben Unicruz</h6>
        <hr>
    <h3><u><em>Games Analysis</em></u></h3>
    <h4>Halo 4</h4>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HMOWXHlxUM0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <br/>
        <hr>
    <h3><u><em>Game Mechanics</em></u></h3>
    <h4>First Person Shooters</h4>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/13iMO9s-q0c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <br/>
    <h4>Jumping in 2D</h4>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yuRRPT-Isp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <hr>
    <h3>Game Ratings</h3>
    <form>
        <table id="GameRating">
            <thead>
                <th>Title</th><th>Genre</th><th>Score</th>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="New Row" onClick="newRow()"></input>
        <input type="button" value="Delete Last Row" onClick="deleteLastRow()"></input>
    </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: Does not change the table on the bottom of the page.

Comment: @AlphaD1, what changes do you need? added elements have no styles, if you want them to have another look, you need to add them classes, id or styles in Javascript code